# What is the function of "de" in this sentence?

Tags: de

I came across this in the story 'Le Saint Inconnu' by Blaise Cendrars (1937):

> tout ce menu peuple de métis, pauvre, noble, taciturne, rêveur, superstitieux, artiste, doux, complaisant et sale...

What is the *de* doing? I would have expected to read simply 'ce menu peuple métis, pauvre [etc.]'.

Comment: The idea behind de is made up of.

Comment: peuple métis would be an adjective. de métis is a noun. And métis as a noun exists in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)) **I.** − De prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent.
> **A.** − De exprime le point de départ.
> **6.** Le point de départ est un tout dont on tire une partie.
> **b)** **Subst. + de**. *De* a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif. Cf. *de*<sup>2</sup> et *des* **II** (en parlant d'une partie, d'un ensemble, d'un élément d'un tout).
> **β)** [En parlant d'un tout nombrable, en partic. un subst. coll.]
> ♦ Une troupe d'enfants; un couple de rossignols; des escouades de motocyclistes.
> ♦ L'âpre essaim des corbeaux voraces (Hugo, Légende,t. 3, 1877, p. 30).

Le point de départ, ou tout dont on tire une partie, est l'ensemble des métis (tous les métis qui existent au moment où l'action se passe) et qui est un tout nombrable ; « de » indique que le peuple est constitué d'une partie  (indéfinie) de ce tout  .

Le tout pourrait être partageable, comme par exemple un ananas, et alors « **α)** »
serait le sens parent qui explique « tranche d'ananas ».

Answer (score 3):

*Un peuple de métis* means "a crowd / nation of mixed race people"

*Un peuple métis* would mean " a mixed race people" - you'd lose the sense of a crowd.

Comment: Thanks lkl, that expalins it. Congratulation, BTW, on your online tutorial resource. I'm a long-term subscriber because I think it's the best thing of its kind.

Comment: I don't think one can translate into English un peuple by a nation or crowd.